# Parsing a value in a reader C#

Tags: c#, datareader

In my project I use this

```
List<DataClassLibrary.LineData> ScaleGroup1 = 
      list.FindAll(ld => ld.ScaleGroup == DataClassLibrary.ScaleGroup.GROUP_1);
```

To break that line down. I have a reader in my LineData class that finds the scale group which is two numbers (44). Then it takes my list ld and then compares them to my scalegroup which will be 1 or 2 or 3. Upon not showing any rows in my ASP table I checked my `list` and it showed there was no values with just 1 2 or 3. So I needed to parse out the first value and get the second one to compare to mt my ScaleGroups. I created the parse and the `list` still returned two numbers(44 instead of 4). How can I fix my method to parse the second value out only?

I have tried stepping into this to make sure this working (DataClassLibrary) and it does not get to this part of the code. Any changes I make to my class seems like it never happens. For instance I change the query still runs the old one.

```
 while (reader.Read())
 {
     LineData ld = new LineData();
     ld.WorkOrderNumber = reader["WorkOrderNumber"].ToString();
     ld.PLUNumber = reader["PLUNumber"].ToString();
     ld.ItemCode = reader["CaseGenNum6"] != DBNull.Value ? reader["CaseGenNum6"].ToString() : string.Empty;
     ld.BrandCode = reader["CaseGenNum9"] != DBNull.Value ? reader["CaseGenNum9"].ToString() : string.Empty;
     ld.CasesRemaining = (int)reader["CasesRemaining"];
     ld.ScaleGroup = (ScaleGroup)reader["ScaleGroup"];//take this and parse out second number
     string str = ld.ScaleGroup.ToString();//parse method
     char secondDigit = str[1];
     ld.ScaleGroup = (ScaleGroup)secondDigit;//setting ScaleGroup to parsed record
     list.Add(ld);

  }
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Are you saying that you're not getting into the reader because it's empty? Is the data coming from SQL or what datasource?

Comment: @owen79 yes data is coming from sql data source. The best way to describe what is going on is any change I make to my class it seems like it doesn't acknowledge it happened.

Comment: There is two questions here, if you're not getting into the while loop in the first place then that suggest the reader is empty. With regard to the class changes not being acknowledged, my first check would be that your project dependencies are in order and the build configuration is building th DataClassLibrary project

Comment: If your data reader is empty, as it seems to suggest when you say its not entering the code block. Can you execute the underlying query in SQL Management Studio to check it's actually returning data?

Comment: @owen79 yes checked many times it returns data. I used breakpoint and t it never enters my method to get to the reader.

Comment: check the timestamp of the DataClassLibrary you're using and make sure it's consistent with your expected build time. Also, clear your temporary asp.net files - in a folder such as C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET - it may be that they're cached